# How to prevent re-rendering of items in v-for statement when adding to list

Tags: javascript, vuejs2

So i'm using v-for to render posts in a feed (similar to a facebook feed), and a lot of these posts have links that are displayed as embedded iframe previews. I'm using a 3rd party service to retrieve these embeds, I just inject the link and it will asynchronously load (after the post ui piece has already rendered on screen).

I have an infinite scroll behaviour, so when you scroll lower, more posts are loaded by appending more objects to the END of an array (using .push), then the v-for renders them accordingly and therefore more embeds are loaded, everything good.

However the problem lies when I add a new post object to the BEGINNING of the feed array using .unshift(). When I do this, all subsequent posts in the array seem to re-render the embed preview iframes (the previews disappear then re-load).

I'm wondering why this happens and how I would prevent this as obviously it's not great UX as it can heavily lag the user's browser.

Currently using vue 2.5.17

Comment: I would either not use the `v-for` and use js to insert the feeds into the dom or I would create the embeds somewhere in the dom and hide them then use some sort of id to reference them and copy them into the feed.

Comment: @KubwimanaAdrien interesting approach, thanks for a solution

Comment: Are you using the `:key` attribute along with v-for? https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html#key Also it should be a unique identifier, not the index (as it changes when unshifting).

Comment: @yuriy636 yes i am using a unique key based on the post id, still re-renders

Comment: You can try to wrap things in `<keep-alive>`.

Comment: @ZachLeighton looked promising, but keep alive is more for toggling between conditional components, not for v-for, atleast from what i can understand from the documentation and testing it out on my code